# Forcing Computed Fields on a Document to Recalculate using SSJS

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, computed-field

Is there a way to force a documents computed fields to recalculate from within an Xpage, without saving the document?

I have a subform on a Notes database with many computed fields, these contain some complex calculations involving time range calculations. The database is used as both a web and client application. For the custom control containing the fields I don't want to have to recreate all the calculations, so have a computed text value bound to the computed form on the document.

On the subform as you tab through entering the information the computed fields are recalculated. On the custom control I have a refresh button which saves the datasource and does a partial refresh of the data entry section, but this can cause some errors or document save conflicts.

I will recreate the calculations if need be, but I just wondered if there is a slicker way of achieving this before I start that process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DominoDocumentData object has computeDocument() and doComputeDocument() methods. I'm not sure what they do. If you look at the class for your XPage / Custom Control under Local\xsp you can see them. Using the variable name for your datasource, e.g. document1, you will be able to get a hold of the DominoDocumentData object and case it to that class.

Comment: Paul, I looked for the DominoDocumentData object but could not find it.  Here is the path I took:  switch to Package Explorer view, expand Local\xsp folder, expand XPageWithDocDataSource.java, and dissapointed to not see any reference to DominoDocumentData !! what am I missing? am I following the correct path?  wrong perspective or  view?

Comment: Try creating a blank XPage with just a dominoDocument datasource and it should have it. Alternatively using the Designer search should find it. Alternatively, it looks like the Javadoc is publicly available here http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/DesignerAPIs/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/DominoDocumentData.html

Comment: Ah, got it now.  I had stopped too early.  Needed to open XPageWithDocDataSource.java, right-click the class on the import statement, and then Open Type Hierarchy ... very useful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "computed fields on a document". A document is completely unaware how its items got their values. 
Computed fields live on forms. You have 2 options (you can use one or both).

- when defining a documentDatasource you can specify that the formulas are executed on load and/or save.
- use the document.computeWithForm method of the NotesDocument